# Rails 6.1 redirecting to json page on render

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a situation where I'm posting comments using channels and upon updating rails to 6.1 I've gotten a weird error. The create method looks as follows

```rb
def create
    offer = Offer.find(comment_params[:offer_id])

    @comment = Comment.new(
      user_id: current_user.id,
      offer_id: offer.id,
      content: comment_params[:content],
      attachment_file: comment_params[:attachment_file]
    )

    if @comment.save
      CommentChannel.broadcast_to offer, message: render_comment(@comment)
      render json: { success: true }
    else
      render json: { success: true }
    end
  end
```

and the `render_comment` method is as follows

```rb
def render_comment(comment)
    render_to_string(partial: "offers/comment", locals: {comment: comment}, layout: false)
end
```

This is working as it were, but now suddenly whenever I'm creating a new comment it redirects to this page

[image]

the comment gets created and everything seems to work as it did except for this random redirect. What might be the cause of this? I assumed it had something to do with `render_to_string`, but couldn't figure this out.

Also here is the form

```
<%= form_with model: Comment.new, id: 'new-comment' do |f| %>
 <%= f.hidden_field :offer_id, value: @offer.id %>
 <div>
 <%= f.text_area :content %>
 <div class="mt-3 flex items-center justify-between">
  <%= f.submit "Comment", id:"comment-button",%>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Are you using 'form_with' in your view by any chance? There were some changes to 'form_with' helper, regarding to whether it defaults to HTML or XHR. If that's the case, adding 'local: true' option should fix that.

Comment: I am indeed! Updated the form to the question. Unfortunately, I'm still getting this redirect with local: true.

Comment: Adding local: false did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is not a redirect. You're sending a non XHR request and the server is returning the rendered JSON and an `application/json` content type.

You can see that as it has triggered the fancypants JSON syntax highlighting and formatting in the browser.

What you really want it something like:

```
# POST /offers/1/comments.json
def create
  offer = Offer.find(params[:offer_id])
  comment = offer.comments.new(comment_params) do |c|
    c.user = current_user.id
  end
  if comment.save
    CommentChannel.broadcast_to offer, message: render_comment(comment)
    render json: comment,
      status: :created,
      location: comment
  else
    render json: { errors: comment.errors.full_messages },
      status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end

# ...

private

def comment_params
  params.require(:comment)
        .permit(:content, :attachment_file)
end
```

This give a much better API and you can test the response code in your integration tests (you are testing aren't you? ;) ) instead of parsing the JSON.

A 201 Created response does not have to contain the entity in the response but its really useful for ajax to get the newly created object back.

You should also nest the route instead of using a hidden input:

```
# routes.rb
resources :offers do
  resources :comments, only: [:create]
end
```

```
<%= form_with model: [offer, comment], 
  id: 'new-comment', 
  "data-type" => 'json', 
  remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_area :content %>
  <div class="mt-3 flex items-center justify-between">
    <%= f.submit "Comment", id:"comment-button",%>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Since Rails 6.1 `form_with` does not default to `remote: true` and instead you can opt in with the `config.action_view.form_with_generates_remote_forms` option. Rails UJS defaults to `application/javascript` as the type for XHR requests.

Since you're sending the correct response codes it will trigger the appropriate ajax handler methods:

```
let form = document.getElementById('new-comment');

// Handle when a comment is created
form.addEventListener("ajax:success", (event) => {
  const [data, status, xhr] = event.detail;
  console.log(data); // the newly created comment
});

// Handle invalid input
form.addEventListener("ajax:error", (event) => {
  const [data, status, xhr] = event.detail;
  console.log(data.errors); // the errors
});
```